# Read from database and display contents

Tags: php, mysql

The sample code displays the location. I have 4 other columns of data I would also like to search for. I am new at this and trying to learn as I go, please try to explain as much as you can but rather than give me the answer please guide me.

I've tried adding the additional 4 forms and then at the top I tried to add additional areas apart from location around WHERE location = :location"; but then the form starting acting up and wouldn't accept the additional areas.

Also tried to add:

```
$location = $_POST['location'];
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$paypal = $_POST['paypal'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$serial_no = $_POST['serial_no'];
```

Which didn't work either.

```php
<?php

/**
 * Function to query information based on 
 * a parameter: in this case, location.
 *
 */

require "../config.php";
require "../common.php";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (!hash_equals($_SESSION['csrf'], $_POST['csrf'])) die();

  try  {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM clients2
            WHERE location = :location";

    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(':location', $location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
  } catch(PDOException $error) {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
  }
}
?>
<?php require "templates/header.php"; ?>

<?php  
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if ($result && $statement->rowCount() > 0) { ?>
    <h2>Results</h2>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Fullname</th>
          <th>PayPal</th>
          <th>Email Address</th>
          <th>Serial</th>
          <th>Location</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($result as $row) : ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["client_id"]); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["fullname"]); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["paypal"]); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["email"]); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["serial_no"]); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["location"]); ?></td>

        </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <blockquote>No results found for <?php echo escape($_POST['location']); ?>.</blockquote>
    <?php } 
} ?> 

<h2>Find user based on location</h2>

<form method="post">
  <input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="<?php echo escape($_SESSION['csrf']); ?>">
  <label for="location">Location</label>
  <input type="text" id="location" name="location">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Results">
</form>

<a href="index.php">Back to home</a>

<?php require "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

To be able to have the 4 extra fields show any results. At the moment the Location field displays the results.

Comment: how does you database look like?

Comment: You'll have to explain what do you mean by that as in look like?

Comment: how does your table look like, maybe you have some typographical errors

Comment: Table shows exactly whats in the table :

          <td><?php echo escape($row["fullname"]); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["paypal"]); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["email"]); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["serial_no"]); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo escape($row["location"]); ?></td>

Comment: If you want to send multiple search terms(?) to your script at the same time - then you want _one_ form containing multiple term fields, not _multiple forms_ …

Comment: That is what I meant, the multiple forms was referring to the actual form code <form>